# replace() does not take into consideration the "g" flag when used with string instead of regex

Tags: javascript, string, replace

```
var a = 'Construction,Airports,Construction|Commercial Construction,Construction|Education,Construction|Healthcare,Construction|Housing,Construction|Industrial Construction,Construction|Other,Construction|Ports,Construction|Rail,Construction|Residential Construction,Construction|Roads & Bridges,Social Infrastructure|Commercial Construction,Social Infrastructure|Education,Social Infrastructure|Healthcare,Social Infrastructure|Housing,Social Infrastructure|Other,Social Infrastructure|Residential Construction';

alert(a.replace('|', ',', 'g'));
```

On chrome, it is replacing only the first occurrence of `|`, while using the `g` flag in the regex form of the `replace()` function, it replaces all the occurrences:

```
alert(a.replace(/\|/g, ',', 'g'));
```

**Can anyone please help me understand if I'm doing something wrong in the first form of the replace? is that the intended behavior or is it a bug?**

Comment: `str.split(search).join(replace)` is the standard trick to replace a substring globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this format: `a.replace(/\|/g, ',')` **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rGzqw/)**

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

> The use of the flags parameter in the String.replace method is
>   non-standard. Instead of using this parameter, use a RegExp object
>   with the corresponding flags.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `flags` parameter [is non-standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Parameters); using a `RegExp` object with the corresponding flags is the standard usage.

Some browsers may support the flags with the string version (see [this example on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Example%3a_Using_global_and_ignore_with_replace)), but it shouldn't be relied upon.

For instance, your example appears to work fine in Firefox, but not in Chrome.

Reference: [ECMA-262 5.1 § 15.5.4.11](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.11)